# Integrating Authentication For Different Web Applications

Tags: authentication, integration

What is the best way to share authentication information between two unrelated applications. Is there a standard for this?

For example, if I use MoinMoin and vBulletin on a same website, is it possible for both systems to share the same authentication information (i.e. so, a user will only need to signup for 1 to have a common login for both)?

Answer (score 0):

Possible yes.  Worth the effort? I'm not sure.  I would look at one of the open authentication systems such as OpenID to get this kind of thing to work.